# Changing Furnace to Direct-Vent, can i get rid of these pipes?

Tags: hvac

My 96% furnace uses a PVC pipe to exhaust the combustion gases to the outside. The intake is currently taken in through a inlet similar to the exhaust on the left side of the furnace. It does not connect to any pipes, it simply sucks air in from the room. I believe the two large pipes coming from the attic are to supply combustion air. Can I run similar PVC to the outside for the intake and then be able to remove these two pipes?

[image: image of HVAC]

You can see straight through the pipe into the attic.

[image: image of HVAC]

I also have a 40,000 btu water heater in the room. The room is 11'x8'x9' so 792 cu. ft.

[image: water heater description]

Comment: Are there any other fuel burning appliances in the space? Is the furnace designed for an air intake, or will you be installing a new unit? Where do you live? what codes apply?

Comment: There's a water heater and soon a dryer that'll burn NG. The furnace is designed to be both direct and indirect vent. I'm not sure what codes apply, I'm not sure what these vents are even for.

Comment: If the water heater isn't also direct vent, then you'll still need the openings.  These are combustion air vents, which are almost certainly required by your local codes.

Comment: I have added the chart from the water heater to the question. The room it's in is well above the required minimum space for needing outside air.

Comment: How tightly is the building sealed (is it an older home, or a modern high efficiency home)?

Comment: It was built in the 70's, so not very tight

Comment: Then yes, If you convert the furnace to direct vent, you can likely get rid of the combustion air vents. However, before doing so, I'd check with the local building department just to be sure.